# How to make animated GIF Screenshot for presentation?

Tags: animation, photoshop, gif, animated-gif

Before answering FYI , I know how to make animated gif's but the smoothness image below is linked , how to get that !
[Here is the animated image](https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/152914967/disp/e5c73aefc4d469ffc40eb0b5a53ba7cf.gif)

Comment: Can you try and reword your question - it is hard to understand. What have you done so far? What is the problem with your current results?

Comment: open the link ... you will see animated gif image .. i just wanted to know how to create that animated gif is there any tool for the easingness that gif has !